# linq for textbox and datagrid column compare mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I needed some help to write a linq query in mvvm for the textbox value to compare it with datagrid column value. thanks

```
                    foreach (fruittype element in resultCollection)
                    {
                    byte tb = Convert.ToByte(textboxN1);

                    if (tb == datagrid1.ColumnName1)
                    {
                        element.IsMatched = true;
                    }
                    }
```

Comment: in your sample code has some errors, why u declaring element but never using from it inside foreach? and how to checking tb which type is byte with textbox? Pls write clearly

Comment: i am using element inside if of foreach. is it wrong ? i am converting textbox value which is in string to byte so that i can compare byte value with datagrid column value ColumnName1

Comment: why you need foreach for one column value or you want to check it with column all values?

Comment: all column values. there are many values where i need to perform search operation to those values

Comment: Pls see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860612/c-sharp-wpf-datagrid-search-for-a-value-in-a-column-return-the-row-index

Comment: okay let me try this way. but i am not using sql. values are retrieving directly from save file of xml format.

Comment: I'm very confused by your logic. Are you trying to check if the textbox value is equal to datagrid1.ColumnName1, and if so, you want to set EVERY element's IsMatched to true? Your question needs clarification on this, because saying that you want to compare the textbox value to the datagrid column value is an incomplete statement...compare it and "then do what?" And what is the relationship to the each element in resultCollection, to the textbox or the the datagrid column name?

Comment: i have to compare the textbox value to one of the datagrid column value named columnName1, comparing them further should perform search operation. so am trying to do it using if condition or writing a linq query.

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve that on this way

var list = resultCollection.Where(x => Convert.ToByte(textboxN1) == datagrid1.ColumnName1).ToList();

foreach(var item in list)
{

```
item.IsMatched = true;
```

}